# JavaFX not correctly setting up layout

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have been struggling with JavaFX for 2 days now, I have a scene I ought to display on my screen,but I have a problem, when I run the below code in SceneBuilder the code seems perfect everything seems in place, even with the `Preview Window` option it works but the moment I run my code an issue pops up, the stage seems to be `5+` more bigger in width than the scene, hence I get a layout which has a sort of white area on the right hand side, here is my code

the first Image is showing Layout Results when I run the code, the Asphalt layer is my scene, you can see the white layer on the far right end of my layout and down part but When tested in Scene Builder in the second Image all seems ok, my asphalt layer has filled up everything.

[image: When tested in Scene Builder all seems ok, my asphalt layer has filled up everything][image: an Image of my Layout Results when I run the code, the Asphalt layer is my scene, you can see the white layer on the far right end of my layout and down part]

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="600.0" minWidth="1000.0"
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainViewController">
<children>
  <StackPane minHeight="600.0" minWidth="1000.0">
     <children>
        <BorderPane minHeight="600.0" minWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ecf0f1;">

        </BorderPane>
     </children>
  </StackPane>
```

and my java Code for Inflating the fxml file

```
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    primaryStage.setTitle("");        
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/mainWindow.fxml"));
    Region root = (Region) loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);


    primaryStage.setTitle("");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    primaryStage.show();


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.toFront();

    // Set minimum size based on client area's minimum sizes
    // Set minimum size based on client area's minimum sizes

    Stage loginStage = (Stage) (this.scene.getWindow());
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
    primaryStage.show();
    loginStage.close();
```

Comment: which IDE? can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: I am using eclipse, let me try and upload

Comment: I have added images, the first one shows how it looks in scene builder, the asphalt scene fills up the entire stage but in image 2 the scene does not cover the button and right sides properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything really wrong in this code, but setting the min size of the stage could be causing this problem, it's useless anyway because the stage uses the size of the scene. If this doesn't work try setting the max size for the Anchorpane or the size in the constructor of the scene in addition to the first solution.
(Btw, I wouldn't use Region for the root container, Parent or the container name are the more typical solutions)

Edit: Where's the code pf the controller? Does it do anything?

Comment: i fixed it, the `AnchorPane` was the issue, I do not know what was wrong with it, all I did was make the `stackpane` child of `AnchorPane` parent and all was fine

Answer (score 0):

it seems the `AnchorPane` was the problem, I do not know why but after removing it and setting the child `StackPane` as parent all was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug for non-resizable stages on Windows - 
see http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8089008